Google Oauth CASA tier-2 verification, which app should i submit for security scanning exactly?
We are building application suite in communication space which requires Restricted scopes of Gmail API.
We have submitted our application for Oauth verification and Google team has asked us to provide CASA Tier-2 verification certificate as it requires restricted scopes. We have gone ahead with the TAC security as our assessor which will scan our app.
Now, we have iOS mobile client, Android mobile client and REST API (total 3) top level components in our system, out of which only our REST API handles the complete flow of Oauth and uses the Gmail API, none of the clients directly communicate with Gmail API neither in sensitive nor restrictive way, the whole business logic is on server side.
My question is, do we need to scan our mobile apps in this case then?
Help is appreciated, if you need more context please comment below.
I tried searching about this on forums, casa website and google’s oauth verification documentation but no clear answer was provided

You need to ask Google we can't comment on their verification process

Irony is Google asked me to ask on the StackOverflow explicitly

Stack overflow has no control over what third party websites say.  Only Google can answer your question ask for guidance

Try posting here: https://issuetracker.google.com/
